# Posso ter transitions diferentes na mesma tag?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, css-transições

Olá pessoal gostaria de saber se posso ter mais de um transition na mesma tag?
Porque implemento os transitions para as propriedades mas não funciona? 
*Ou isso ocorre porque não defini os valores da propriedade antes.

```
.trans {
    background: #F00;
    height: 250px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition: height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 1.25s ease-in-out;
}

.trans:hover {
    height: 10px;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Exemplo com o codigo.
http://jsfiddle.net/hphf0c74/

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Recomendo usar o all. transition: all 1.25s ease-in-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira como você fez, a transição de `height` simplesmente sobrescreve a de `opacity`. Você precisa listar todas as propriedades que vão sofrer transição de uma vez só, separadas por vírgulas, assim:

```
.trans {
    background: #F00;
    height: 250px;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out, height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out, height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out, height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out, height 1.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s 1s ease-in-out, height 1.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Valew! Muito obrigado era exatamente isso. Precisando de algo estamos ai XD

Comment: Obrigado, fico feliz em ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

Opa! Você não pode usar duas vezes a transition. O segredo é usar todas as propriedades em apenas um transition. Você também precisa definir uma altura e opacidade inicial em `.trans` e uma final em `.trans:hover`.

Segue minha solução: http://jsfiddle.net/hphf0c74/1/

**CSS**

```
.trans {
  background: #F00;
  -webkit-transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3s ease;
  transition: height .25s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3s ease;
  height:0px;
  width:100%;
  opacity:1;
}

.trans:hover {
  height: 30px;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Valew! era exatamente isso cabaçada minha. Precisando de algo estamos ai XD

Comment: @DouglasdosSantos valeu!